# Use chained concatenation and one-space string \" \"

Tags: python, pycharm

```
world = 'World'

hello_world =hello +''+ World
print(hello_world)      # Note: you should print "Hello World"
```

result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  /PycharmProjects/Introduction to Python/Strings/Concatenation/concatenation.py", line 4, in <module>
    hello_world =hello +''+ World
NameError: name 'World' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `World` != `world` variable name is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Python variables are case sensitive, so the variable `World` is not the same as `world`.

`hello_world =hello +''+ World` should be `hello_world = hello + '' + world`

Comment: how to send the screen shot ?

Comment: Have you defined hello at all? If not, you need to do that before this works

Comment: hello = "Hello"
world = 'World'

hello_world = hello +''+ world
print(hello_world)      # Note: you should print "Hello World"